# Test connection with TLSharp

Tags: c#, telegram

I'm trying to send a message with TLSharp but cant,i dont get errors,it just execute the code and do nothing;

This is my method.

```
public virtual async Task SendMessageTest()
        {
            string NumberToSendMessage = "+55199999999";
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NumberToSendMessage))
                throw new Exception("TESTE");

            // this is because the contacts in the address come without the "+" prefix
            var normalizedNumber = NumberToSendMessage.StartsWith("+") ?
                NumberToSendMessage.Substring(1, NumberToSendMessage.Length - 1) :
                NumberToSendMessage;

            var client = NewClient();
            var tsk = client.ConnectAsync();
            await client.ConnectAsync();


            var result = await client.GetContactsAsync();

            var user = result.users.lists
                .OfType<TLUser>()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.phone == normalizedNumber);

            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new System.Exception("Number was not found in Contacts List of user: " + NumberToSendMessage);
            }

            await client.SendTypingAsync(new TLInputPeerUser() { user_id = user.id });
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerUser() { user_id = user.id }, "TEST");
        }
```

This is my code,is says is wait for activation,what should i do?

[image]

I'm trying to use this method also,but it doenst return nothing too.
I'm new to TelegramApi,what i'm doing wrong?

```
await client.ConnectAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should authorize first! And only after that you can call other methods. Look [at the examples here](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp/blob/master/TLSharp.Tests/TLSharpTests.cs).

In general you should write something like this:

```
var hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync(NotRegisteredNumberToSignUp);
var code = Console.ReadLine(); //Input the code, that was sent to your phone
var loggedInUser = await client.MakeAuthAsync(NotRegisteredNumberToSignUp, hash, code);
```